# Jquery.sheet Hide formula bar and template functions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spreadsheet

I'm using jquery.sheet in order to display working spread sheets in my website.
I have 2-3 questions that i need help with, adn i couldnt find enough information about them on google or jquery.sheet's documentation.

1. is there a built in way to hide the formula bar from the spreadsheets?(i dont want users to be able to see/edit the formulas inside the cells

2.i'm using custom template in order to provide the sheet with some preloaded formulas for some cells. For example

```
<div id="sheetParent" title="test cells">

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td data-formula="C6"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="227">Cashflow </td>
        <td width="77"></td>
        <td width="77"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>For an Individual</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Template 1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Period</td>
        <td>Per month</td>
        <td>3 months</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>€</td>
        <td>€</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Inflow</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Recurring income:</td>
        <td></td>
        <td data-formula="B10*A1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td></td>
        <td data-formula="B11*A1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rent from property</td>
        <td></td>
        <td data-formula="B12*C6"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Income from services</td>
        <td></td>
        <td data-formula="B13*C6"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Income from deposits</td>
        <td></td>
        <td data-formula="B14*C6"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Other income</td>
        <td></td>
        <td data-formula="B15*C6"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Non-recurring income</td>
        <td></td>
        <td data-formula="B17*C6"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Income from deposits</td>
        <td></td>
        <td data-formula="B18*C6">type in a value and press Enter to activate</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    <td>Click + Enter 0 to activate</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Totals</td>
        <td data-formula="SUM(B11:B19)"></td>
        <td data-formula="SUM(C11:C19)"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outflow</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Recurring expense</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rent for property use</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Loan payments</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Electricity, water consuption</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Telephone, internet use</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Petrol and gas consumption</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Insurance fees</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Medical fees</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Daily expenses</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Non-recurring expense</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Personal development fees</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Surplus :  money to spend wisely</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Deficit :  reduce expenses</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

When i do it like this, the spreadsheets loads but the formula is not working as expected. I either have to retype it inside of on of the cells or type a number inside a cell in the same row in order for all the formulas in the third (and aboe the Sum()) to work. (example if i type 300 in cell B11, Cell C11 must update it's value to B11*C6. Instead it doesnt do anything. If though i go to cell C19 ( which is the last cell before the Sum() is called, and type in a number(lets say 0), all the formulas above it update an work as they should be)

Why is that ?

3.Is there a way to load an excel spreadsheet directly into jquery.sheet ot do i have to do it manually? also how do i initialize 2 or more worksheets on the same page ? (excample SHEET1,SHEET2 etc)?

thanks for any replies

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to jquery.sheet is [spreadsheet-js](http://github.com/netbrain/spreadsheet-js)